# stop rank 30 update on nominatim-docker build

Tags: postgresql, docker, nominatim

I am installing [nominatim-docker 3.0](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/3.0) on VM with 128 GB RAM and 8 vcpus with 1TB disk. I am almost going to run out of disk(only 25 GB left). I am wondering if it is ok to restart pgsql service to stop rank 30 index/update. Here are last few steps of docker file.

```
...
...
...
RUN service postgresql start && \
    sudo -u postgres psql postgres -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='nominatim'" | grep -q 1 || sudo -u postgres createuser -s nominatim && \
    sudo -u postgres psql postgres -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='www-data'" | grep -q 1 || sudo -u postgres createuser -SDR www-data && \
    sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS nominatim" && \
    useradd -m -p password1234 nominatim && \
    chown -R nominatim:nominatim ./src && \
    sudo -u nominatim ./src/build/utils/setup.php --osm-file /app/src/data.osm.pbf --all --threads 6 --osm2pgsql-cache 20000 && \
    service postgresql stop

EXPOSE 5432
EXPOSE 8080

COPY start.sh /app/start.sh
CMD /app/start.sh
```

My question: Are [rank 30](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview#Indexing.2Faddress_calculation) updates so critical for geocoding? 
If I restart postgresql at this stage of installation, would nominatim api be functional? 
My current install is for the test purpose and I just want to checkout nominatim local.